# How to use templates and/or using`with structs?

Tags: c++, templates, using

I have the following definitions:

```
template<typename T>
using refval= std::pair<int, T>;

template<typename T>
using indexedvals = std::vector<refval<T>>;
```

In order to make my code more readable i wanted to use a `struct` instead of a `pair` in the definition of `refval` - so that in my code i could use a member name like `index` instead of `first`, or `value` instead of `second`.

So i tried

```
template<typename T>
typedef struct_t refval {
    refval(int iRefCell, T tValue):m_iRefCell(iRefCell),m_tValue(tValue){};
    int m_iRefCell;
    T   m_tValue;
} refval;
```

But here the compiler complained with "error: template declaration of ‘typedef’".

Then i tried

```
template<typename T>
using refval = struct refval_t {
    refval_t():m_iRefCell(-1){};
    refval_t(int iRefCell, T tValue):m_iRefCell(iRefCell),m_tValue(tValue){};
    int m_iRefCell;
    T   m_tValue;
};

template<typename T>
using indexedvals = std::vector<refval<T>>;
```

Here i got the following complaints

```
Sampling.h:12:32: error: types may not be defined in alias template declarations
   12 | using refval = struct refval_t {
      |                                ^
Sampling.h:23:7: error: conflicting declaration of template ‘template<class T> using indexedvals = std::vector<refval_t>’
   23 | using indexedvals = std::vector<refval<T>>; 
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

So what i want to do is to define my templated struct in such a way that i can use it in a `using` statement as in the code snippets at the beginning of this post.

How can i achieve this?

(probably an analogous question would be: how is `std::pair` implemented so that this works?)

Comment: Don't code C++ as C.  `template<typename T> typedef struct_t refval { ... } refval;` should just be `template<typename T> struct refval { ... };`

Comment: `struct`/`class`/`union`/`enum` etc do not need `typedef`s in C++. They are type-defined out-of-the-box.

Comment: Why are you using the C pattern `typedef struct foo {} foo;` in C++?

Comment: btw I often wish my pairs members had better names, but isnt `mi_RefCell` as generic and meaningless as `first` is already?

Comment: Is your `refval` supposed to hold a reference to a `T` or an actual copy of the thing?

Answer (score 4):

Frankly, you are guessing how it works, and this is never going to end well.

You can define a template:

```
template<typename T>
struct refval_t {
    refval_t():m_iRefCell(-1){};
    refval_t(int iRefCell, T tValue):m_iRefCell(iRefCell),m_tValue(tValue){}
    int m_iRefCell;
    T   m_tValue;
};
```

and then you can define an alias template:

```
template<typename T>
using refval = refval_t<T>;
```

However, I don't think you actually need the alias when you can just use the template directly.

Note that you should initialize the `m_tValue` member also in the default constructor. As you have it currently, it is too easy to read from it before it is initialized and invoke undefined behavior.